# Rails Devise Invitable not working uninitialized constant Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, actionmailer, devise-invitable

Invitations Controller

```
class InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController

 def new
 end

 def create
 end

end
```

routes.rb

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :invitations => 'users/invitations' }
```

application_controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
 # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
 protect_from_forgery with: :exception
 before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

 protected

 def configure_permitted_parameters
 # Only add some parameters
 devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:accept_invitation).concat [:email]
 # Override accepted parameters
 devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:accept_invitation) do |u|
  u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation,
         :invitation_token)
 end
end
```

users_controller

```
def new
 @user = User.new(:invitation_token => params[:invitation_token])
 @user.email = @user.invitation.recipient_email if @user.invitation
end
```

When I go to the '/users/invitation/new I get the error 'uninitialized constant Users'. What am I missing? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

`devise_for :users, :controllers => { :invitations => 'invitations' }`

instead, also if you override the methods , you probably need to call the parent , by using `super` like this:

```

```
class InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController

   def new
     super
   end

end
```

```

Comment: Ok so I got it working, sort of, it sends the email but I get an error 'ActionController::UnknownFormat' instead of redirecting me to the homepage